# Program crashes when trying to scan strings into array

Tags: c

I am writing a program to intake exactly 5 peoples last names and their votes.  Which will display the names of the people entered, the corresponding votes, and also the winner.

I need the names of the people into one array of strings.  That is where the program crashes.  Not sure if I can modify this to make it work or if I need to redo it.

the malloc function seems to be a recurring fix for this type of problem ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int TotalVotes(int voteArray[],int size)
{
    int Sum=0;
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        Sum+=voteArray[i];
    }
    return Sum;
}

int Winner(int voteArray[],int size)
{
    int max;
    max=0;
    if (voteArray[1]>voteArray[max])
        max=1;
    if (voteArray[2]>voteArray[max])
        max=2;
    if (voteArray[3]>voteArray[max])
        max=3;
    if (voteArray[4]>voteArray[max])
        max=4;
    return max;
}

void main()
{
    char nameArray[5];
    int voteArray[5],Total,winner;
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        voteArray[i]=0;
    }
    for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        printf("Enter the name of the candidate number %d\n",j+1);
        scanf("%s",nameArray[j]);
        printf("Enter that persons number of votes\n");
        scanf("%d",&voteArray[j]);
    }
    Total=TotalVotes(voteArray,5);
    winner=Winner(voteArray,5);
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n","Candidate","Votes Received","% of Total Votes");
    for (int y=0;y<5;y++)
    {
    printf("%s\t%d\t%0.2f\n",nameArray[y],voteArray[y],(float)voteArray[y]/Total);
    }
    printf("The Winner of The Election is %s\n",nameArray[winner]);
}
```

Comment: `char nameArray` is not an array of strings. It's an array of 5 characters. Thus your scanf function is crashing by trying to place a string in such array. Try use a double pointer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char nameArray[5];` is should be like `char nameArray[5][20];`

Comment: Yeah that works 100%... I am not exactly sure why? I know it is a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, in C, strings are represented by character arrays (char* or char[]).

Also, you should get fgets instead of scanf with strings for two reasons:

1. Fgets helps prevent buffer overflow because it knows the size of the string in advance.
2. Fgets will always run because it does not leave characters in the input buffer like scanf does.

The prototype for fgets looks somewhat like this (you can use stdin for the FILE pointer to read in from the keyboard, but realize that fgets keeps newlines):

```
fgets( char *output_variable, unsigned int string_length, FILE *input_file );
```

Also, if you use scanf, you should do a lot more error checking for invalid input.